# How does thin magically "take over" when included in the gemfile/required in the app?

Tags: ruby, rack, thin, puma

I `gem "thin"` and `require 'thin'` are added to any (seems like) Rack app, it will automatically be chosen when the app is launched via `rackup`, *instead of* WEBrick.

How does rackup know to use thin? What if I use unicorn or Puma or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rack's source code](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/4453f50aa0d36f0fca08a19d75270c7fb28d2b74/lib/rack/handler.rb#L46-L57) states has three default servers in the following order: Thin, Puma and WEBrick.

Rack will attempt to 'mount' these three servers unless the `PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN` or `RACK_HANDLER` environment variables are set.

This behavior might change in the future, but for now only thin and puma will be recognized automatically when their gems are included.